# How do I convert a doubly recursive method to a loop?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, for-loop

Here is my simplified doubly recursive method. It does nothing useful, but illustrates the required recursive invocations:

```
void Main()
{
    Test(2, 3, 4);
}

int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;

void Test(int i1, int i2, int v)
{
    if (v == 0)
    {
        (n1 + n2).Dump();
    }
    else
    {
        n1 = i1 + 10;
        n2 = i2 + 20;
        Test(n1, n2, v - 1);
        Test(n2, n1, v - 1);
    }   
}
```

I can't quite figure how I can write this as a loop to see if performance improves.

I've corrected the example for the obvious errors.

Comment: Yes, it can be done faster using iterative approach. My approach (in my answer) approx. 2 times faster when testing with v=25.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever can be done recursively can also be done using stacks. 
Assuming you only want the functionality that you have written in your example:

i1 and i2 will eventually be added to the sum of global variables n1, n2. you can sum up them and assign the result to n1 or n2 in the beginning of the code to simplify the functionality. And using a stack, you can do something like:

```
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;

void Test2(int i1, int i2, int v)
{
    Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>(new[] {v});
    n1 = i1 + i2;

    while (s.Any())
    {
        v = s.Pop();
        if (v == 0)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(n1 + n2);
        }
        else
        {
            int tmp = n1;
            n1 = n2 + 10;
            n2 = tmp + 20;
            s.Push(v - 1);
            s.Push(v - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs the same as the recursive code:

```
125
155
155
215
215
245
245
335
335
365
365
425
425
455
455
```

Comment: Great! It works! Just one question... how did you come up with n1 = i1 + i2 ??

Comment: +1 I'm not sure that it would garner any performance gain as this is how the compiler normally implements recursive calls. Good alternative though.

Comment: @Aditi i1 and i2 are never used alone, only their summation is used

Comment: It is possible to do this witout stack also.

Comment: You could use `Stack<int>` instead of `Stack` (to get rid of the cast/boxing) and then use `while (s.Any())` instead of `while (s.Count != 0)`.

Comment: You could even try pre-sizing the Stack (using one of its constructors)

Comment: @DominicKexel , xanatos You are right, I have modified the code.

Comment: @Faruk Sahin  Your approach has defect. After its execution values of n1 and n2 not the same as after execution of recursive approach. However, OP did not say is it important for him or not.

Comment: @Faruk Sahin Also, surprisingly this approach is several times slower than initial recursive approach in my tests (1 000 000 runs of example provided, no output to screen). And it is 20x times slower than my MyWayTwo approach :)

Comment: @SergeyS Instead of runnning 1 000 000 times the same test, running the test with bigger values of v might be a better test since creating a Stack object has a fairly high overhead. I haven't thought about any performance gains though. I just wanted to show a quick example on how recursive code can be rewritten using a stack.

Comment: @Faruk Sahin - Also have tried one run with v=25, your approach is still slower than recursive one. I'm not say it is bad, just curious.

Comment: @Totero: most compilers will *not* turn recursive methods into iterative ones (some will switch to tail recursion in some instances). This saves on method calls and stack size at the expense of heap memory.

Comment: @Carra - if you are interested you can take a look at my solution for this problem

Comment: @Totero On my environment this code actually works significantly slower than initial recursive one. For real gain in performance see my approach below.

Answer (score 3):

Try this iterative (without Stack) approach:

```
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;

void MyWay(int start1, int start2, int plus1, int plus2, int v)
{
    n1 = start2 + plus2 * v;
    n2 = start1 + plus1 * v;
    for (int i = 0, pow = 1 << v; i < pow; i++)
    {
        if ((i & 1) == 0)
        {
            int temp = n2;
            n2 = n1;
            n1 = temp;
        }
        for (int mask = i; mask > 0 && (mask & 1) == 0; mask >>= 1)
        {
            n1 += plus1;
            n2 += plus2;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(n1 + n2);
    }
}
```

Should be called as:

```
MyWay(2, 3, 10, 20, 4);
```

All constants from your example are passed to function, so it is totally universal.
Also, important fact is that **values of n1 and n2 after completion of function will be exactly the same as after completion of your recursive approach**.

---

### Concerning performance:

Surely, it will give some time improvement, but not much. But it will give with big input parameters.
Also my approach does not consume additional memory (recursive and stack approaches consume).

---

### Update about performance:

I have tested locally your and my approaches - calling each 1 000 000 times. Results are the following:

**Recursive: 225.1774 ms**

**Iterative: 152.1194 ms**

---

### [Update] If you do not need n1 and n2 after function completed you can make code shorter:

```
void MyWayTwo(int start1, int start2, int plus1, int plus2, int v)
{
    plus1 += plus2;
    int n = start1 + start2 + plus1 * v;
    for (int i = 0, pow = 1 << v; i < pow; i++)
    {
        for (int mask = i; mask > 0 && (mask & 1) == 0; mask >>= 1)
            n += plus1;
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

Ouput when calling `MyWayTwo(2, 3, 10, 20, 4);` :

```
125
125
155
155
215
215
245
245
335
335
365
365
425
425
455
455
```

### Even more simplified solution:

```
void MyWayTwo(int s1, int s2, int p1, int p2, int v)
{
    p1 += p2;
    s1 += s2;
    for (int i = 1 << v, p = i << 1; i < p; i++)
    {
        for (int m = i; (m & 1) == 0; m >>= 1)
            s1 += p1;
        Console.WriteLine(s1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to only use the endresult I can give you this code

```
protected void TestIt(int i1, int i2, int v)
{
    int tot = 0;
    for (; v > 0; v--)
        tot = tot * 2 + 30;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(tot + i1 + i2);
}
```

if you need intermediate results, unfortunately this code won't be able to give that to you.